# Mount cifs with group permissions

Tags: permissions, fstab, cifs

I want to mount windows network share with different permissions based on 
group owners should have read/write permissions, others, only read permissions

I am adding the following line in /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.OO.PP/Public           /mnt/storage            cifs    nofail,iocharset=utf8,noperm,uid=XXX,password=%^%^,gid=XXX,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775   0    0
```

What happens is not only group owners, but all users has read/write access, instead other users to have readonly access

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you might need to use `...,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,nounix`

Despite those options are deprecated you can use `fmask` (for files), `dmask` (for directories) or `umask` (for files and directories).
It works as the normal octal permissions but subtracted from 7. For instance if you want to set the permissions to `0775` you will need to set it `0002` in the umask (e.g. `umask=0002`).

Comment: thank you, but adding nounix does not change anything and using umask instead prevents mounting at all

Comment: ok the problem was with noperm  option, replacing with perm solved it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this parameters:

```
//host/share    /net/share        cifs   user,noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,workgroup=workgroup,credentials=/foo/credentials    0 0
```

Permissions will be shown as:

```
drwxr-xr-x directory
-rwxr-xr-x file
```